# Как зная ключ массива найти значение

Tags: php, массивы

Eсть две переменных. Одна это сам массив и другая это GET с нужным ключом.

```
$_GET['country'] - ключ
$wo['countries'] - массив
```

Вопрос в том, как зная нужный массив и соответственно ключ по которому нужно искать, найти значение ключа?

```
$result = массив, ключ = значение.
```

Это ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Я ничего не понял

Comment: @АлексейШиманский аналогично.

Comment: `$ckey = $_GET['country']; $result = $wo['countries'][$ckey] ?? null` ?

Comment: @teran вначале было я тоже так подумал, но countries говорит о том, что это массив. И тогда этот вариант отпадает

Comment: @teran, это помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
$wo['country'] = $wo['countries'][$_GET['country']];
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: в целом было бы неплохо проверить, что в массиве есть такой ключ, иначе получите notice от пхп

Comment: @teran, спасибо за совет, проверку вставлю. Хотя опять же я слабо представляю как юзверь получит такой notice даже в теории, ибо список стран форичится из массива, и по клику на определённую, данные отправляются в обработчик который выводит строну на основе ключа.

Comment: никогда не надо доверять тому, что приходит от юзера. В теории он просто изменит URL в адресной строке браузера.

Comment: @teran, хорошо. Спасибо что объяснили. Проверку в любом случае вставил.